# My ServerFault blog feed has been filled with SuperUser posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog-overflow

My Google Reader feed from the Server Fault blog about 15 minutes ago just became a flood with a mix of Super User posts:

[image]

Something's not quite right...

Comment: The same just happened to me using Thunderbird.